# How do I format HTML Fields for TFS / VSTS workitem queries

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-power-tools, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use the Team Foundation Server Power Tools (tfpt) to create workitems programmatically. I need to create many test cases this way. The power tools are largely undocumented unfortunately but I have traced it down to one last remaining bits. I need to be able to create test steps alongside the test case. This is done with a field called `Steps=`

For Example: `/fields: "Title=My Title;Steps="`

Now digging as far as I could in the field explorer, the text that follows steps has to be "HTML formatted" But I have no idea what Microsoft's definition of HTML is and what the tags should be in order to properly serve the data.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: It seems that you can't to do it with tfpt tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is general HTML formatted value, for example `<div></div>, <B></B>.` The detail value will be encoded. You can get encoded value via [online tool](https://mothereff.in/html-entities#%26lt%3BDIV%26gt%3B%26lt%3BDIV%26gt%3B%26lt%3BP%26gt%3Bst%26lt%3BB%26gt%3Bep%26lt%3B%2FB%26gt%3B1%26amp%3Bnbsp%3B%26lt%3B%2FP%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2FDIV%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2FDIV%26gt%3B).

On the other hand, there is additional information indicate test step actions, for example: `<step id=”4” type=”ActionStep”> <parameterizedString isformatted="true"></ parameterizedString></step>.`

A simple step value:

```
<steps id=\"0\" last=\"4\"><step id=\"2\" type=\"ActionStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;st&lt;B&gt;ep&lt;/B&gt;1&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description /></step><step id=\"3\" type=\"ActionStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;st&lt;I&gt;ep&lt;/I&gt;2&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description /></step><step id=\"4\" type=\"ActionStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;s&lt;U&gt;te&lt;/U&gt;p3&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description /></step></steps>
```

[image]

I recommend that you can create test case by using TFS/VSTS API (Client SDK or Rest API)

C# code:

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("XXX", "XXX");
     TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("[collection url]"), cred);
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();

            var workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tpc.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
            Project teamproject = workItemStore.Projects["ScrumStarain"];
            WorkItemType testCaseType = teamproject.WorkItemTypes["Test Case"];

            WorkItem testCase = new WorkItem(testCaseType)
            {
                Title="TestCaseApi2"
            };
            testCase.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps"].Value = "[previous sample value]";
            testCase.Save();
```

Also, you can get a test case step value by using this code:

```
var wit = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(408);
object stepValue = wit.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps"].Value;
```

Rest API: [Create a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item)

Body sample:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "newTestcase"
  },
   {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps",
    "value": "<steps id=\"0\" last=\"4\"><step id=\"2\" type=\"ActionStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;st&lt;B&gt;ep&lt;/B&gt;1&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description /></step><step id=\"3\" type=\"ActionStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;st&lt;I&gt;ep&lt;/I&gt;2&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description /></step><step id=\"4\" type=\"ActionStep\"><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;s&lt;U&gt;te&lt;/U&gt;p3&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted=\"true\">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString><description /></step></steps>"
  }
]
```

Comment: you are a GODSEND. If there is anything I can do to repay you, please let me know!!